# How to merge two sublists from two different lists in the original

Tags: python, list, merge

Both of my lists have sublists inside them

**list1=** `[['+', '+', '-'], ['+', '-', '+'], ['-', '+'], ['+', '+', '+']]`

**list2=** `[['x1', 'x2', '2x3'], ['2x1', 'x2', 'x3'], ['x1', 'x3'], ['3x1', '2x2', '4x3']]`

How can I concatenate the list1 and list2 based on the same index and save the result in another list?

My desired outcome would be:

```
list1 = [['+x1', '+x2', '-2x3'], ['+2x1', '-x2', '+x3'],['-x1', '+x3'],['+3x1', '+2x2', '+4x3']]
```

So far I've tried doing it for 1 sublist only but i had no luck in keeping the sublist as is

```
for pair in itertools.product(list1[0], list2[0]):
    matrix3_with_signs.append(''.join(pair))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check with

```
x=[[m+n for m,n in zip(x,y)]for x , y in zip(list1,list2)]
x
Out[135]: 
[['+x1', '+x2', '-2x3'],
 ['+2x1', '-x2', '+x3'],
 ['-x1', '+x3'],
 ['+3x1', '+2x2', '+4x3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the nested listcomp you can use the function `map()` with the operator `concat` (or `add`):

```
from operator import concat

[list(map(concat, i, j)) for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]
```